# WCat throwing error from ubr file generated from WCat Scenario Creator

Tags: iis, wcat

I used the WCat Scenario Creator (http://fiddler2wcat.codeplex.com/) to generate the scripts of many requests through a website.

I had to add the "port:8888;" to every request. Then, after the "All clients connected, Test beginning." response, the test produced this error:

Invalid code received.
Error accepting remote connection.

I knew the first two requests worked so it was an issue with what was wrong with the next, 3rd, request.

The request looked like

```
        request {
        id = "3";
        url = "/Content/Telerik-Kendo/textures/highlight.png";
        verb = GET;
        cookies = True;
        secure = False;
        statuscode = 304;
        setheader {
            name = "Accept";
            value = "image/png, image/svg+xml, image/*;q=0.8, */*;q=0.5";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Referer";
            value = "http://server.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888/Home/Winpoints/?sessionid=502hhfoij5ef4jedzouxz02z&low=0&high=150&companyid=3&verticalmarketid=8";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Accept-Language";
            value = "en-US";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "User-Agent";
            value = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Accept-Encoding";
            value = "gzip, deflate";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Host";
            value = "server.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8888";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "If-Modified-Since";
            value = "Thu, 27 Sep 2012 05:47:46 GMT";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "If-None-Match";
            value = ""0ed9e9e739ccd1:0"";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Connection";
            value = "Keep-Alive";
        }
        setheader {
            name = "Cookie";
            value = "ASP.NET_SessionId=502hhfoij5ef4jedzouxz02z";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, at least for this problem was the double quotes around the value of the "If-None-Match" header.

```
            setheader {
            name = "If-None-Match";
            value = ""0ed9e9e739ccd1:0"";
        }
```

Changing this to have 1 opening and closing double quote fixed it.

```
            setheader {
            name = "If-None-Match";
            value = "0ed9e9e739ccd1:0";
        }
```